# Who first said "You're being machmir on pikuach nefesh"?

Tags: shabbat, sources-mekorot, pikuachnefesh-danger-life, provenance, quotations

I've been hearing the phrase "This is not being *meikil*<sup>1</sup> on Shabbos, this is being *machmir*<sup>2</sup> on *pikuach nefesh*<sup>3</sup>" for a long time. I've heard it quoted from [R' Chaim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Soloveitchik), from the [Gra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vilna_Gaon), and from various and sundry other sources.

It has also been, in my experience, applied to eating on Yom Kippur and other instances of *pikuach nefesh*, but I've always understood that the original quote was said about Shabbos.

**Who was the originator of this line? Can I find it anywhere, "inside"?**

---

<sup>1</sup> *lenient*
<sup>2</sup> *stringent*
<sup>3</sup> *the obligation to preserve one's life, which overrides Shabbos and most other mitzvos*

Comment: I don't have the time right now, but perhaps someone can create a [glossary](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/581/5323) entry for my keywords? ...I think the footnotes are ugly (though better than parentheses, in this case), and the question would have a better appearance if the keywords were linked to MY glossary definitions.

Comment: It is attributed [here](http://daf-yomi.com/Forums/Message.aspx?id=19342) to R. Moshe Feinstein and [here](http://www.yaban.org.il/design2/webPro/project/katava1.asp?codeClient=2128&CodeSubWeb=0&id=263061&projId=43913) and [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_48001_101.pdf) to R. Chaim Soloveitchik.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer seems to be most probably [R. Chaim Soloveitchik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Soloveitchik). This is recorded [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41176&st=&pgnum=270&hilite=). Additionally,  Ishim V'shitot of [R. Zevin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Yosef_Zevin) (ed. Kol M'vaser, 2007, pp. 51-2) attributes it to him:

> מחמיר לפי הגדרתו של ר' חיים עצמו. וכך היה אומר: כלום אני מקיל באיסורים? אדרבה אני מחמיר בפיקוח נפש.

This is consistent with R. Soloveitchik's approach to such matters, as R. Zevin further discusses there.

Comment: Incidentally, the majority of attributions for it I found online were to R. Chaim

Comment: the second source quotes שמואל ביאלובלוצקי. I cant find any info. about him other than that he wrote a book in 1971.

Comment: Thanks! I was kind of hoping for a source *inside* R Chaim; but if he never wrote it....I'll have to see if I can find a copy of Ishim V'shitos, then.