# What should I do if I don't know whether I'm in a pikuach nefesh situation?

Tags: pikuachnefesh-danger-life, safek

Suppose I find myself in a situation where I am not sure whether my life is sufficiently in danger to warrant *halachot* of *pikuach nefesh* to come into play. What should I do in this case? Am I supposed to (e.g.) violate *Shabbat* in this case?

To be clear, I am not talking about a situation where I do not know how much danger I am in (I am having sudden chest pains and I'm not sure whether it's a heart attack or something more benign. My understanding is that this is the category of *safek pikuach nefesh* and it is treated the same as *pikuach nefesh* situations). I am talking about the situation where I am aware of the level of danger and I have a *safek* about whether the risk is sufficient to constitute *pikuach nefesh* (e.g. [I am caught driving in a severe blizzard and *Shabbat* is about to begin](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/66749/1713)).

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/61809/is-an-on-call-doctor-allowed-to-read-non-emergency-text-messages-on-shabbat

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This question is discussed by [Rabbi Kaganoff](http://rabbikaganoff.com/tag/pikuach-nefesh/)

“One must desecrate Shabbos even if there is only a slight possibility that the situation is dangerous. One does not need a professional opinion or an expert physician. Whenever one is uncertain whether the situation is dangerous, he is required to desecrate Shabbos (Shu’t Tashbeitz 1:54).”

Once you suspect that this could be a situation of *Pikuach Nefesh* then you need to be "machmir on the halacha of Pikuach Nefesh".  [Who first said "You're being machmir on pikuach nefesh"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53739/who-first-said-youre-being-machmir-on-pikuach-nefesh)

Comment: This even applies to something like a doctor checking what the message on his phone was on Shabbat: a medical emergency, or some random email?

Comment: @Scimonster I would imagine so. I see doctors carrying pagers on _Shabbat_ all the time.

Comment: @Scimonster - I asked exactly your question on MY a few months ago. I have to hunt for the link. If you locate it before me, please post a "related" comment / link.

Comment: @DanF I think I confused everyone with my question mark. I was making a statement; the question mark was the doctor's not knowing what the message was.

Answer (score -1):

By all means !!!
Don't even consider a "Pikuch nefesh" situation as "Hilul Shabbat" - but act without delay in ANY way you can to save a life. Even if it is only a slight suspicion. And NEFESH is not only physical, it also means Mental or a worrisome situation.

Comment: Please quote references, otherwise it's just your personal opinion!